# How to deploy Spring Boot application war to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Similar things have been asked before, but all the answers I have seen are "It just works!".  Sadly, it does not for me.

My problem is: When I deploy a war file to Elastic Beanstalk, I get a pile of errors from catalina.out saying "Failed to start component" (Log below).

I've gone through the Spring Boot tutorial, am building with Gradle, and have added the 'war' plugin so I can build a deployable war file.  When running locally, I can access the "Greetings from Spring Boot!".  I haven't made any changes to this project other than the prescribed ones to generate a deployable war file, and attempting to change the listening port for the project.

I've mucked about with the load balancer config, allowing port 8080 inbound and outbound, and added the "FullAccessEC2Instance" security role to IAM thinking I didn't set the permissions up right (but this doesn't have the 'it just works' feel).

Currently spinning my wheels guessing at what to do now.  I'm considering testing deploying to Heroku and seeing if it has problems there also, or if it's a problem with my AWS config.

```
    2015-06-21 14:52:02.946  INFO 2644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 11.831 seconds (JVM running for 21.292)
21-Jun-2015 14:52:02.970 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1719)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.isEnabled(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

21-Jun-2015 14:52:02.972 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1719)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21-Jun-2015 14:52:02.980 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 18,574 ms
21-Jun-2015 14:52:02.985 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Jun-2015 14:52:03.015 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Jun-2015 14:52:03.026 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 18751 ms
```

Thanks everyone!

EDIT:

Here is the full catalina.out for loading the instance:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.4.RELEASE)

2015-06-21 15:31:43.017  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on ip-172-31-6-84 with PID 2034 (/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar started by tomcat in /usr/share/tomcat8)
2015-06-21 15:31:43.096  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2427d57f: startup date [Sun Jun 21 15:31:43 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-06-21 15:31:45.158  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-06-21 15:31:46.622  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3526 ms
2015-06-21 15:31:47.884  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] .b.a.w.JettyWebSocketContainerCustomizer : NonEmbeddedServletContainerFactory detected. Websockets support should be native so this normally is not a problem.
2015-06-21 15:31:50.306  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-06-21 15:31:50.312  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-21 15:31:50.312  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-21 15:31:50.312  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-21 15:31:50.312  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-21 15:31:50.313  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-21 15:31:50.313  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2015-06-21 15:31:51.178  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2427d57f: startup date [Sun Jun 21 15:31:43 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-06-21 15:31:51.388  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String hello.HelloController.index()
2015-06-21 15:31:51.391  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-06-21 15:31:51.391  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-06-21 15:31:51.493  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-06-21 15:31:51.493  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-06-21 15:31:51.637  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-06-21 15:31:53.442  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2015-06-21 15:31:53.443  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.443  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.453  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2015-06-21 15:31:53.457  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.457  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.458  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.458  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.458  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.459  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.459  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2015-06-21 15:31:53.459  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-06-21 15:31:53.516  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-06-21 15:31:53.561  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2015-06-21 15:31:53.844  INFO 2034 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 12.088 seconds (JVM running for 21.354)
21-Jun-2015 15:31:53.859 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1719)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.isEnabled(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

21-Jun-2015 15:31:53.866 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1719)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21-Jun-2015 15:31:53.873 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 18,712 ms
21-Jun-2015 15:31:53.878 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Jun-2015 15:31:53.896 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Jun-2015 15:31:53.904 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 18879 ms
```

Comment: I've made some progress on this - It seems I can deploy it from WAR file if I remove the Jetty dependencies from the build.gradle file.  This is annoying since the tutorial from Spring Boot specifically calls the configuration out on being "both deployable from war and jar", when it seems to not be.

Comment: could you please post what you build.gradle file looked like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to only have either Jetty or Tomcat in the dependencies section in build.grade.  Seems this is correct in the documentation, but I misunderstood that I was meant to remove either/or, depending on how I wanted to deploy it.